# How to delete every element of specific type in php?

Tags: php, html

Hey so i have a use of a php function that would delete every element of specific type in php. More specifically i want to delete all the labels on my website, e.g:

```
DOMDocument::deleteAllElementsOfType("label");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you outputting the html in the first place?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You cannot filter / modify stuff which you do not have access to. How do you currently produce / output html? Note that php runs on the server and not on the client.

Comment: On a website? i just write the html normally in a .php file and i've seen function like DOMDocument::createElement or DOMDocument::getElementById so im just assuming, if theres another way that its perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ways:

With [XPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php):

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHtml('
<form>
    <label>a</label>
    <input />
    <label>b</label>
    <input />
    <label>c</label>
    <input />
</form>
', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query("//label") as $label) $label->parentNode->removeChild($label);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Result

```
<form>
    
    <input>
    
    <input>
    
    <input>
</form>
```

With [getElementsByTagName](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname)

*Due to it being a live document you convert the iterator to an array with [iterator_to_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array)*

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHtml('
<form>
    <label>a</label>
    <input />
    <label>b</label>
    <input />
    <label>c</label>
    <input />
</form>
', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

foreach (iterator_to_array($dom->getElementsByTagName('label')) as $label) $label->parentNode->removeChild($label);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Result

```
<form>
    
    <input>
    
    <input>
    
    <input>
</form>
```

See it online: https://3v4l.org/WJpqk

You could extend DOMDocument if you want to add your own methods

```
<?php
class Document extends \DOMDocument {
    function __construct(string $version = "1.0", string $encoding = "") {
        parent::__construct($version, $encoding);
    }
    
    public function deleteAllElementsOfType(string $type) {
        foreach (iterator_to_array($this->getElementsByTagName($type)) as $item) $item->parentNode->removeChild($item);
    }
}

$dom = new Document();

$dom->loadHtml('
<form>
    <label>a</label>
    <input />
    <label>b</label>
    <input />
    <label>c</label>
    <input />
</form>
', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$dom->deleteAllElementsOfType('label');

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: loadHtml is part of the example, you would use what you currently have

Comment: wrap your script in a `ob_start(); all script here; echo ob_get_clean();` the woos of echoing as you go

Comment: Ok i decided. I am going to mark your question correct, because it anwsers the question i asked, and then im gonna delete all my comments and refactor the my entire website because what i was trying to do with deleting labels was very stupid.

Comment: thanks, np I guess you want something like https://3v4l.org/3OPSu